# Dataclass breaks when adding a decorator to it

Tags: python, pygame, python-dataclasses

The error I get is `TypeError: must be real number, not Field` from the rendering code which tries to rotate an image.

It *only* does this when I try to decorate `live` with `activated_range`.

```py
@dataclass
class EntityZombie(entity_manager.Clickable, entity_manager.Rotatable, entity_manager.BaseEntity):
    max_distance = 125
    max_health = 20.0
    # more class variables go here
    # there's also a field here, which gets initialized to 0 without any issues
    last_attack: int = field(init=False, default=0)

    @utils.activated_range(250)
    def live(self, game) -> None:
        ...
```

The decorator tries to check the distance from the entity to the player, and only run things if it's close enough to the player:

```py
def activated_range(activate_distance: float):
    def decorator(method):
        def new_func(instance, game):  # self.live(game)
            # if the distance is too large, do not execute the method (live)
            if instance.player_distance(game.player) > activate_distance:
                return
            method(instance, game)
        return new_func

    return decorator
```

Rotatable is an ABC that specifies the field `rotation`:

```py
class Rotatable(BaseEntity, abc.ABC):
    rotation: float = field(init=False, default=0.0)
    # some more methods that are not relevant here
```

Normally, the value of `rotation` correctly gets set to 0 (as it's the default), but whenever I have the `live` decorated with `activated_range`, it will always set the value of `rotation` to a dataclass `Field` instead of the number it's supposed to be defaulted to.

I thought this might be an issue with the decorator, but `live = utils.activated_range(250)(live)` also gives the same error.

Even weirder, on some tries when I run this, one or two of the `EntityZombie`s actually do have their rotations set correctly, but then eventually one of them doesn't and the program crashes. The debugger shows that `rotation` is set to the actual field, but the dataclass should be making it into the float (as that's what the `default` is set to). It did that when I didn't decorate that function, so why not now?

[image]

Why does adding the decorator to one method break the dataclass and have the fields not default correctly? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/greateric/Documents/PYTHON/immatureidiotsimulator/main.py", line 131, in <module>
    Game()()
  File "/home/greateric/Documents/PYTHON/immatureidiotsimulator/main.py", line 43, in __call__
    self.mainloop()
  File "/home/greateric/Documents/PYTHON/immatureidiotsimulator/main.py", line 126, in mainloop
    self.redraw_queue()
  File "/home/greateric/Documents/PYTHON/immatureidiotsimulator/main.py", line 112, in redraw_queue
    entity.blit_me(self.asset_manager)
  File "/home/greateric/Documents/PYTHON/immatureidiotsimulator/entity/entityzombie.py", line 56, in blit_me
    super().blit_me(asset_manager)
  File "/home/greateric/Documents/PYTHON/immatureidiotsimulator/entity/entity_manager.py", line 197, in blit_me
    surface = pygame.transform.rotate(surface, self.rotation)
TypeError: must be real number, not Field
```

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: `Rotatable` must *also*  (I think) be decorated with `dataclass` in order for `rotation` to be processed. Inheritance doesn't "inject" the attribute into the definition of `EntityZombie` to be processed there, it only provides additional paths for attribute lookup to succeed at runtime.

Comment: @chepner I tried that but it still gives the same error.

Comment: Why was this closed? Decorating `Rotatable` does actually work (I'm an idiot and messed it up last time), but I would still like to know why it worked properly when the function was left alone and not decorated. I don't believe any code relevant to the question was left out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce it here, with an even more abstract and smaller minimal code, and invariably, I got the `field` value instead of a number whenever the mixin class was not declared a dataclass.

So, I am confident there is some code in there that is setting the rotation of your EntityZombie instance to 0 prior to `.blit_me()` being called - that would explain why *some* of the instances work. Also, it makes sense that this behavior is prevented to run whenever `activate_range` is in effect: the decorator effect will prevent that other code to set the instance value to 0.

The workaround, as you had found out, is just to declare whatever mixins you have with declared `field` attributes as dataclasses as well - this will "activate" the field descriptor for the most derived classes.

Comment: Yeah, I do update it in `live`, so I never noticed it not being initialized properly until adding the decorator which sometimes cancels running it.